# Create new Vec<T> from a vector Vec<T> and data T

Tags: rust, immutability

I want to be able to create a new vector `c: Vec<T>` from `a: Vec<T>` and `b: T` where `c` is equal to `b` appended to `a`, without using mutables. Say I have this code-

```
fn concat_vec<T>(a: Vec<T>, b: T) -> Vec<T> {
    return Vec::<T>::new(a, b);
}
```

I am aware this does not work, because `Vec::new()` has no input parameters. What I am wondering is if there is an function or macro in `std::vec`  that can initialize a vector from another vector and a set of additional values to append onto the vector. I know a function can be created very easily to do this, I am just wondering if functionality exists in the standard library to work with vectors without them being mutable in the first place.

Comment: None that i know of. Rust is pretty low-level, so they generally expect you to write out the costs of your code. In this case, internally, such a macro would have to clone the vector, append to the clone, and return it. And that's exactly what a function you might write would do, explicitly, as well.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, that's what I am gathering from all of the implementations I have seen. Rust seems to be sitting in the middle, in between a) having sufficient abstraction to be able to append to lists and create a new Vec while being immutable (like Haskell) and b) having low-level access where the vector array can be allocated and set before the Vec object itself is conceptualized (like C), without using unsafe.

Comment: I have the impression that you are trying to mimic the `cons` operation, but for vectors. This is a terrible idea, as `cons` is supposed to be a cheap operation (which it is on lists), but for a vector it's very expensive. You should try with a linked list (which is not easy in Rust...).

Comment: @BlackBeans While what you say is good advice in general, in this particular case what the OP asks for can be done cheaply, as shown in Kaplan's and my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vec::from_iter` should work if you're willing to use iterators.

```rust
pub fn concat_vec<T>(a: Vec<T>, b: T) -> Vec<T> {
    return Vec::from_iter(a.into_iter().chain(std::iter::once(b)));
}
```

**Edit(s):** Also as far as I have seen: the most common way to work with vectors, slices, and arrays is through the use of the `Iterator` trait and the functionality it provides.

Also on the topic of speed: the above approach is slightly faster *if you avoid cloning*. On my computer iterators take about 1.571µs per call whereas cloning and pushing to a vector took 1.580µs per call. (Tested by running the functions 300 000 times on a debug build.)

Comment: [It works much better with recursion, too!](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/a80969dc61d649a67eb266d21aa32e67)

Comment: Note this will be terribly less efficient than `push()`.

Comment: You want `a.into_iter()`, and then you don't need `t.clone()`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @user4815162342. It makes the function slightly faster than using push by eliminating the clone, and removes the requirement that T be clone for the function to work.

Comment: I have to agree with @ChayimFriedman on this. The iterator is far less efficient than mutating `a` by `push`ing on the new element. This is because `a` is passed as an owned value and the caller would either need to give up or clone the original `Vec<T>` to pass it to the function. If it had been passed as a reference (`&Vec<T>`) or slice (`&[T]`), this solution would be much more applicable.

Comment: *Tested by running the functions 300 000 times on a debug build.* - that is not how Rust code is benchmarked. You should use a release build, or your numbers are meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can use the `tap` crate to push `b` to `a` in an expression that evaluates to `a`:

```rust
use tap::Tap;

fn concat_vec<T>(a: Vec<T>, b: T) -> Vec<T> {
    a.tap_mut(|a| a.push(b))
}
```

This combines the performance benefits of `push()` (in comparison to building a brand new vector) with the elegance of having a short expression.

Answer (score 0):

The universal form of the *inefficient* solution should look like this:

```
fn concat_vec<T>(a: Vec<T>, b: T) -> Vec<T> {
    Vec::from_iter(a.into_iter().chain(std::iter::once(b)))
}
```

…but its strongly recommended to use `push`:

```
fn concat_vec<T: std::clone::Clone>(a: Vec<T>, b: T) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut rslt = a.to_vec();
    rslt.push(b);
    rslt
}
```